# Button URL not working in some browsers

Tags: php, wordpress, internet-explorer

I am trying to call a a specific piece of post metadata ('Buy tickets') to use as a clickable button. The code is working in Safari, but not in other browsers. I am using the latest version of Wordpress. Below is the piece of code that I am currently using:

```
<td>
<input type="button" value="Buy tickets"
onclick="window.open('<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Buy tickets', true); ?>')">
</td>
```

I have also tried using the following script, but this renders the button unclickable:

```
<td>
<button id="<?php $postId = get_the_ID(); echo $postId ?>" style="float:right">
<p>Buy tickets</p>
</button>
</td>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
// Handler for .ready() called.

$("#<?php $postId = get_the_ID(); echo $postId ?>").click(function(){
         window.location="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Buy tickets', true); ?>"
         return false;
    });

    });
</script>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! To see the first piece of code in action please click [here](http://www.thelaughingpod.com/events/upcoming/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
<table class="tickets">
<tr>
    <td><button data-goto="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Buy tickets', true); ? >">Buy tickets</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("table.tickets button").click(function(event) {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr("data-goto");
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks PorridgeBear. If I make the adjustments you've specified and wrap it in <form> tags, will that be okay?

Comment: It's likely because you are not assigning to window.location.href, either that or the return false is preventing the click bubbling. I have also taken the liberty of rewriting your code to be a whole lot cleaner. You only need the script block once by storing the destination URL in a custom button attribute.

Comment: Hi Porridge. Thanks for adjusting my script. I've deployed on the URL previously specified but it's still not clickable. The metadata is loading correctly but not as a link.

Comment: The source code of the URL shows me you are still using the old code.

Comment: This is the source code that I can see live on the URL:    <!-- buy tickets meta -->
      
    <form onsubmit="return false;">
    <table class="tickets">
    <tr>
    <td><button data-goto="http://www.essex-live.co.uk/tickets/d2086/the-laughing-pod-comedy-club/southend-park-inn-palace-hotel/">Buy tickets</button></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("table.tickets button").click(function(event) {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr("data-goto");
    });
    </script>

Comment: Nope. Are you sure you haven't got the live domain pointed to a local development box in your hosts file or something? http://dl.dropbox.com/u/523401/Screen%20Shot%202012-05-16%20at%204.49.24%20PM.png

Comment: I think the site cache might of caused that. Please see a screenshot of what I'm seeing here: http://grab.by/dEOa

Comment: You need to check for errors when running other peoples' code ;) I am missing another }); at the end of the jQuery. Edited my code above.

Comment: I did have a look and gapped the space at the end of a PHP ?> tag. I'm just majorly inexperienced with jscript and jquery! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Tip: use Chrome's Tools > Javascript Console to see if the page is throwing Javascript errors. If it is, it can break ALL Javascript on the page.